# form generation and validation in Perl

Tags: perl, survey, dancer

I am thinking to create a web based survey and I thought the best way would be to describe the questions and the possible answers as a json or yaml file. Then generate the forms from there (possibly spreading several pages). From the same description file I could derive the rules for input validation and then I could use something like [Data::FormValidator](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Data-FormValidator) to validate the results.

In the end I'd like to plug this in a [Dancer](http://perldancer.org/) based application.

I wonder what modules are out there on CPAN that could help doing this?

Answer (score 4):

Check out HTML::FormFu. I've not used it, but I hear good things from the Catalyst community, and some Dancer stuff seems to use it to.